# Finding the points of a circle by using one set of coordinates and an angle

Tags: circles

I know the image below isn't to scale and that the angle isn't quite at the centre point but can we just imagine it is picture perfect....

[image]

I know the coordiantes and point (x,y) lets say they are (1,1) for simplicity, I also know the angle at centre point is 15 degrees. What is the method I use to find the coordinates at x1,y1.

Please note this is not doing my 'homework' for me, despite it being broad. It is part of a project I am on at work and I have simply came to a mind block with this common calculation - cant seem to find it on the internet without it going into arc lengths and pythagoras (which I will later need)

Comment: This is impossible without some more information. Do you know the radius, or the center point, or anything else?

Comment: centre point is 0,0 and yes the radius is known, for simplicity call it 10 arbitrary units

Answer (score 2):

Let's call the radius $r$.
Since the original point $(x,y)$ is on the circle, you can find some angle $\alpha$ such that 
$x = r\cos\alpha$ and $y = r\sin\alpha$. You could get $\alpha$ by calculating `atan2(x,y)`, for example.

Then the new point $(x_1,y_1)$ is at angle $\beta = \alpha - 15^\circ$, so its coordinates are $x_1 = r\cos\beta$ and $y_1 = r\sin\beta$.

Or, a bit more directly:
$$
x_1 = \; x\cos 15^\circ + y\sin 15^\circ  \\
y_1 =   -x\sin 15^\circ + y\cos 15^\circ  \\
$$
This assumes that positive angles (like your 15 degrees) correspond to clockwise movement.