# Coordinates of sector of circle

Tags: circles, coordinate-systems

I know the coordinates of one point on a circle, this point is part of a sector. I know the angle of the sector at the centre of radius, I know the radius and I know the arc length. How do I calculate the coordinates of the other coordinate of the sector ?

[image: Picture]

I have quickly mocked up the problem in the image above, please note it is B I am aiming to find.

Angle in rads = 0.262

Radius = 21

Arc length = 5.5

A = (0.5,21)

Comment: You can use complex numbers to calculate the co-ordinates of the new points . Take the init point as $0.5+21i$ and multiply it with $e^{i\theta}$ where $\theta = $ the radians by which it is rotated

Comment: In contrast to your other question, this time you have *too much* information. The radis and angle tell you the arclength.

Comment: The center is at distance $21$ from $(0.5,21),$ so it can't be $(0,0).$ On the other hand, if the distance is just very slightly greater than $21$ then $(0,0)$ can be the center. At least some of the numbers must be approximations since $21\times0.262 = 5.502$ (not $5.5$).

Answer (score 1):

Same technique as in your other question [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/700211/finding-the-points-of-a-circle-by-using-one-set-of-coordinates-and-an-angle).

Let $A = (x,y)$ and let $B= (x_1, y_1)$. Then
$$
x_1 = \; x\cos(0.262) + y\sin(0.262)  \\
y_1 =   -x\sin(0.262) + y\cos(0.262)  \\
$$

This assumes the center is again at $(0,0)$.